# How do I use MD5 to convert passwords and check a user's credentials against valid credentials?

Tags: java, hash, authentication, md5

I'm very new to Java. I have to write a program that obtains a username and password from the user, converts the password using MD5, then validates the usernames and passwords. The user gets 3 chances to enter the correct information. Once it is correct, I need to display a welcome message. If the incorrect information is entered 3 times, the program needs to exit. I don't even know where to start with this.

I was provided with a file with the MD5 information. I was also provided with a file that contains all of the users information along with the hashed passwords.

These are the user credentials:

```
griffin.keyes   108de81c31bf9c622f76876b74e9285f    "alphabet soup" 

rosario.dawson  3e34baa4ee2ff767af8c120a496742b5    "animal doctor"

bernie.gorilla  a584efafa8f9ea7fe5cf18442f32b07b    "secret password"
```

The MD5 I was provided with is:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;

public class MD5Digest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //Copy and paste this section of code
        String original = "letmein";  //Replace "password" with the actual password inputted by the user
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(original.getBytes());
        byte[] digest = md.digest();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte b : digest) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
        }
        //End copy/paste

        System.out.println("original:" + original);
        System.out.println("digested:" + sb.toString()); //sb.toString() is what you'll need to compare password strings
    }

}
```

I am also supposed to divide my program into 2 separate methods, but that is the least of my worries right now. I have been working on this for a week now, and I haven't gotten very far. Any help would be so appreciated. Here is what I have

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Scanner;

class CredAndPass {
    public static void CredAndPass() throws Exception {
        String original = "letmein";  //Replace "password" with the actual password inputted by the user
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(original.getBytes());
        byte[] digest = md.digest();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte b : digest) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
        }
    }
}
public class AuthSystem {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int i;
        String username = "";
        String password = "";
        for (i = 0; i <= 2; ++i){
            Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter username:");
            username = scnr.next();
            System.out.println("Enter password:");
            String password1 = scnr.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be aware (and tell your teacher/employer) that MD5 is in no way secure for storing passwords. Instead one needs a hash function with a cost factor, which controls the necessary time to calculate a hash (like BCrypt, SCrypt or PBKDF2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we improve `CredAndPass.CredAndPass` to get a `MD5` hash from a given `String`

```
class CredAndPass {
    public static String CredAndPass(String original) throws Exception {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(original.getBytes());
        byte[] digest = md.digest();
        // Note here that I use a StringBuilder instead of a StringBuffer
        // as it is not meant to be shared so no need to use a thread safe
        // builder of String
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(32);
        for (byte b : digest) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
        }
        // Returns the result
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Then we modify a little bit the logic of the `main` method to check 3 times before leaving if not successful

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // A Map for testing purpose representing the login and hash of your existing users
    Map<String, String> credentials = new HashMap<>();
    credentials.put("griffin.keyes", "108de81c31bf9c622f76876b74e9285f");
    credentials.put("rosario.dawson", "3e34baa4ee2ff767af8c120a496742b5");
    credentials.put("bernie.gorilla", "a584efafa8f9ea7fe5cf18442f32b07b");
    // Variable used to know if it was successful or not
    boolean success = false;
    BufferedReader scnr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String username = null;
    // Iterate up to 3 times
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        System.out.println("Enter username:");
        username = scnr.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter password:");
        String password1 = scnr.readLine();

        // Get the hash for the given username
        String hash = credentials.get(username);
        // Check if the username exists and if so check if the hash of his 
        // password matches with the hash of the provided password
        if (hash == null || !hash.equals(CredAndPass.CredAndPass(password1))) {
            // We don't have a match so we keep going
            System.err.println("User or password invalid");
            continue;
        }
        success = true;
        // Exit from the loop as we have a success
        break;
    }
    if (success) {
        System.out.printf("Welcome %s!%n", username);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Could not connect");
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped a lot, although I don't understand what a map is. When I run this, even when I input the correct username and password, it continues to ask me 2 more times. Is there a way to automatically print the success message if the username and password are correct the first time? Or am I doing something wrong still?

Comment: Is there a way to print a unique welcome message to each user? I tried adding separate print statements to the end to replace the "success" but that is not working.